# Queue::after() in laravel 5.1 is not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.1, laravel-queue

I want to run some statements after queue processed but Queue::after block is not being executed, Can anyone help me how to run Queue::after block

```
<?php

namespace test\Providers;
use Log;
use Queue;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Log::info('log1');
       Queue::after(function ($connection, $job, $data) {
       Log::info('log2');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {

    }
}
```

sample output:
in laravel.log:
only "log1" printing

Comment: Please give a code sample so other can reproduce what is not working.

Comment: Please edit your post and put this code there.